# Load a php file to get variable without loading the html?

Tags: php

I want to get a variable from a php file. I've read, that you can use `include 'mypage.php';` and then use the variable. But if I do that it loads the visual part from the other file too (html and css from `<style>` tag).

Other methods are also apreciated.

Kind regards.

I have the var `$screen_name` in file `twitter/index.php` and want to have it in `create.php`

Tried:

```
include 'twitter/index.php';
echo $screen_name;
```

Comment: Please show what you have and are trying to do. Presumption is that `mypage.php` has inline HTML, would need conditionals so it is only outputted when intended

Comment: It sounds like you need to re-organize your code then.  Any PHP file you include will be executed.  If executing your code produces output, then including it produces output.  So if you don't want the output included, you need to change the code.

Comment: try to separate the code part where you have your var declared to another php file then include it in both, the original and the one you're working on

Comment: In addition to Markus's reply, if you are including a file for its variables, that file would normally only contain constants, variables and functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include the PHP file, it will also do the output. But you can suppress it with output buffering.

```
ob_start();
include './mypage.php';
ob_end_clean();

echo $varFromMypage;
```